# How to expose Kubernetes-hosted RabbitMQ to the outside?

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, rabbitmq

We use a kubernetes cluster with installed HAProxy Ingresses. We want to expose RabbitMQ outside of the kubernetes cluster. How is this possible?

Requirement: This is a shared k8s cluster based on OpenShift, where the only way to expose services is using the ingresses.

1. **Management-UI** provides basic REST-endpoints which shall not be used for a big amount of data
2. **STOMP-Websockets** looks really unmaintained. Not only the protocoll but also the client libs
3. **MQTT-Websockets** looks not so bad like STOMP but also not very future-proof
4. **own REST-service** can be lots of work
5. **AMQP** not possible to expose via HAProxy

I can't imagine that we are the first who needs to connect to RabbitMQ hosted in Kubernetes?!?

The client needs to be **.net** based

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation on a package to connect to a RabbitMQ service, or how to expose a RabbitMQ service from a docker container?

Comment: We want to expose RabbitMQ outside of the kubernetes cluster. How is this possible? Best practises.

Comment: Use port mapping as described in the docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/). Basically, RabbitMQ by default listens on port 5672, but you can map that to any external port. Also, if you're question is about how to expose RabbitMQ, then why state/ ask that you're surely not the first and that the client needs to be .NET based

Comment: Yes but kubernetes will not expose TCP/UDP traffic besides the HTTP protocol

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't expose anything, it orchestrates individual docker containers, the containers themselves expose TCP/ UDP ports. You can configure which ports to expose with Kubernetes however, using the `containerPort` option of you containers spec

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that: This is a shared k8s cluster based on OpenShift, where the only way to expose services is using the ingresses.

Comment: With HAProxy Ingress you are able to [expose raw tcp traffic](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/blob/release-0.8/README.md#tcp-services-configmap)

Comment: If you want access to cluster resources from outside you must expose it as `NodePort`, `LoadBalancer` or using `Ingress`. Can you share your configuration YAMLs? Did you hit any error when want to connect to ingress or you didnt try anything yet?

Answer (score 2):

Just define a `Service`of type `NodePort` for every component you want to expose outside the cluster.

By default you'll have to "map" the port from your component to a port in the range [32000-32767], and you'll be able to access your components with those ports

Basically, a NodePort service will make each node of your cluster listen on the port from the service and route the traffic to the right pods on the right port. There is no protocol restrictions as for Ingress/Routes.

[k8s services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

[OCP doc on nodeport](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-nodeport.html)

**[UPDATED]**
This does not answer the problem at all as the requirement as "*the only way to expose services is using the ingresses.*"

Comment: An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type Service.Type=NodePort or Service.Type=LoadBalancer.

Comment: @masterchris_99 exact. So in what defining Services of type Nodeport does not work for your needs?

Comment: As I wrote in the question: Requirement: This is a shared k8s cluster based on OpenShift, where the only way to expose services is using the ingresses

Comment: A kubernetes Ingress resource can only export HTTP(S) services, so you can't use it to expose arbitrary binary / text protocols, like the ones RabbitMQ uses (see https://www.rabbitmq.com/protocols.html). "An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type Service.Type=NodePort or Service.Type=LoadBalancer." (from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at both Traefik and NGINX for the RabbitMQ external access use case. For RabbitMQ, NGINX Ingress ended up being the simpler option for me to expose the AMQP protocol via TCP. It's also the default ingress provider for minikube (if you enable it), which is useful. If anyone has a comparable Traefik example, I'd be interested in it.

Note, there is nothing stopping you from having more than one ingress controller in use on a cluster for different purposes/use cases.

### Setup

spin up a cluster, if using minikube -

```bash
minikube delete && minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.23.0 --memory=4g --bootstrapper=kubeadm --extra-config=kubelet.authentication-token-webhook=true --extra-config=kubelet.authorization-mode=Webhook --extra-config=scheduler.bind-address=0.0.0.0 --extra-config=controller-manager.bind-address=0.0.0.0 --extra-config=etcd.listen-metrics-urls=http://0.0.0.0:2381 --driver=docker
```

After we have a kubernetes cluster, we need a rabbitmq cluster. I'm using the rabbitmq operator to provision -

Install the latest RabbitMQ operator (if necessary)

```bash
kubectl apply -f "https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/releases/latest/download/cluster-operator.yml"
```

wait for operator to be ready

```bash
watch kubectl get pods -n rabbitmq-system
```

namespace for rabbitmq test-cluster

```bash
kubectl create ns test-rabbitmq
```

create the cluster -
test-cluster.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
  name: test-cluster
  namespace: test-rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 1
```

```bash
kubectl apply -f test-cluster.yaml
```

wait for cluster to be ready

```bash
watch kubectl get pods -n test-rabbitmq
```

Next you need a service of ClusterIP type to expose the management portal and AMQP via Ingress, we'll expose ports 5672, 15672 (and if you want to expose the prometheus metrics endpoint, 15692). Port 5671 would be for AMQP TLS.

cluster-service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: rabbitmq
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cluster-service
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: rabbitmq
  name: cluster-service
  namespace: test-rabbitmq
spec:
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
    # - appProtocol: amqp
    #   name: amqp-tls
    #   port: 5671
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   targetPort: 5671
    - appProtocol: amqp
      name: amqp
      port: 5672
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5672
    - appProtocol: http
      name: management
      port: 15672
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15672
    - appProtocol: prometheus.io/metrics
      name: prometheus
      port: 15692
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15692
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-cluster
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

```bash
kubectl apply -f cluster-service.yaml
```

### setup ingress (minikube only!)

```bash
minikube addons enable ingress
#kubectl patch configmap tcp-services -n ingress-nginx --patch '{"data":{"5671":"test-rabbitmq/cluster-service:5671"}}'
kubectl patch configmap tcp-services -n ingress-nginx --patch '{"data":{"5672":"test-rabbitmq/cluster-service:5672"}}'
```

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: controller
        ports:
#         - containerPort: 5671
#           hostPort: 5671   
         - containerPort: 5672
           hostPort: 5672
```

```bash
kubectl patch deployment ingress-nginx-controller --patch "$(cat ingress-nginx-controller-patch.yaml)" -n ingress-nginx
# after the ingress pod is back up and running
telnet $(minikube ip) 5672
# Ctrl+] then quit
```

### setup ingress (helm)

install the ingress-nginx controller (if necessary)

```bash
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
```

This handles exposing the TCP ports for AMQP, it maps those ports to our service ports we created previously -
values.yaml

```yaml
controller:
  replicaCount: 1
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: "192.168.1.251" # IP reserved for ingress. If you omit, you'll be assigned an IP in the avaiable range. Better to specify one.
tcp:
  #5671: test-rabbitmq/cluster-service:5671
  5672: test-rabbitmq/cluster-service:5672
udp: {}
```

create our nginx ingress controller

```bash
helm upgrade -i ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f values.yaml -n ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

Once the nginx cluster pods are up -

```bash
watch kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
telnet $(minikube ip) 5672
# Ctrl+] then quit
```

let's expose our HTTP ingress -
rabbitmq-ingress.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-ingress
  namespace: test-rabbitmq
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: rabbitmq.test
      http:
        paths:    
          - backend:
              service:
                name: cluster-service
                port:
                  number: 15692
            path: /metrics  # optional
            pathType: Exact  
          - backend:
              service:
                name: cluster-service
                port:
                  number: 15672
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: cluster-service
      port:
        number: 15672
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

```bash
kubectl apply -f rabbitmq-ingress.yaml
```

wait for an external address to be assigned to your ingress

```bash
watch kubectl get ingress -n test-rabbitmq
```

Note: you can adjust the ingress to support TLS/HTTPS, but that's beyond the scope of this example.

### hosts entry

add a rabbitmq.test hosts entry mapped to 192.168.1.251 (or whatever IP you assigned, or was assigned to the NGINX Ingress)

### if using minikube

```bash
sudo -- sh -c "echo '$(minikube ip)  rabbitmq.test' >> /etc/hosts"
```

### if using helm installed ingress controller

```bash
sudo -- sh -c "echo $(kubectl get ingress -n test-rabbitmq -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'  rabbitmq.test >> /etc/hosts"
```

example hosts entry -

```
192.168.1.251  rabbitmq.test
```

Verify we get HTML and stats back via ingress

```bash
curl rabbitmq.test
curl rabbitmq.test/metrics # bonus
```

get the rabbitmq management portal user/password (if not exmplicitly specified when the cluster was created)

```bash
kubectl get secret test-cluster-default-user -n test-rabbitmq -o jsonpath='{.data.username}' | base64 --decode
kubectl get secret test-cluster-default-user -n test-rabbitmq -o jsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 --decode
```

You should be able to connect to the management portal using these credentials from a web browser

```
http://rabbitmq.test
http://rabbitmq.test/metrics
```

### minikube expose ingress to host machine

if you're running minikube in a VM, to expose the ingress to the host so you can access the management portal from a web browser, do the following. Then port map 80 (host) to 8080 (vm) in your hypervisor -

```bash
# we forward to 8080 because 80 is a privileged port
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 8080:80 --namespace ingress-nginx
# following for TLS
#kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 8443:443 --namespace ingress-nginx
```

From the .NET client, you can now test connectivity to the TCP port 5672 using the host entry or ingress IP. If running the .NET client from your host machine into a VM (minikube), port forward TCP 5672:5672

That's should do it. I've verified this in minikube and have done the same on actual clusters using helm for nginx ingress.

### multiple cluster considerations

Note: if you're hosting multiple rabbitmq clusters (from a single kubernetes cluster), you'll have to map to different externally available ports on the same ingress IP (e.g. 5782 -> test-rabbitmq-2/cluster-service:5672).

Alternatively, you could run multiple instances of an ingress controller, but there is additional overhead (and complexity) using this approach.